# Visual Studio application name doesn't update taskbar name after renaming project

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, visual-studio-2012

I have a visual studio 2012 express application that was re-named mid project.  The 'Assembly name' in the project properties is the correct name now and all references to the old name have been changed.  (i.e. if I search for the old name in entire solution nothing is found)

When I compile the application the `.exe` file is correctly named but when I pin this to the taskbar the old name is shown.

When checking the folder: `C:\Users\.....\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` the shortcut is the wrong name.  If I manually rename this shortcut the taskbar menu is updated correctly but I can't expect users to do this and I want to find out where the old name still resides so the root problem is fixed.

Installing on a different computer that had no previous versions installed has the same results.

Has someone encountered this before and know how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is being cached by the [Multilingual User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) subsystem.

The correct value to set is in your project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` using `AssemblyTitle` property.

You can find the cache and clear entries by navigating to the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

Just delete then entry for your app.

If you move your updated app to a new machine that has never run a previous version of the app (or even just change the folder where your app is running from) it should query your application again and get the correct name.